# Redshift Spectrum : Getting no values/ empty while select using Parquet

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift-spectrum

I have tried using textfile and it works perfectly. I am using Redshift spectrum. To increase performance, I am trying using PARQUET. The table gets created but I get no value returned while firing a Select query. Below are my queries:

CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE gf_spectrum.order_headers

( 
header_id numeric(38,18) ,
org_id numeric(38,18) ,
order_type_id numeric(38,18) )

partitioned by (partition1 VARCHAR(240))

stored as PARQUET

location 's3://aws-bucket/Spectrum/order_headers';

Select * from gf_spectrum.order_headers limit 1000;

Also, does PARQUET require partitioning compulsory? I tried that as well, and the table got created. But while retrieving data, I got an S3 Fetch error of invalid version number which did not happen with the text file. Is it something related to PARQUET format?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Have you tried using AWS Glue crawler on the spectrum file and pointing a Redshift Spectrum external schema to the resulting database? That way it works for me.

Comment: I think this is the solution I will try soon. Thanks.